# .Net Framework 4 installation did not succeed: HRESULT 0xC80003F3

Tags: installation, dotnet-framework

I just tried to install the .**Net Framework 4** on my **Windows 7 64 bit** system.
The installation did not succeed - HRESULT **0xC80003F3**

From the log file:

OS Version = 6.1.7600, Platform 2
OS Description = Windows 7 - x64 Enterprise Edition
CommandLine = C:\ea195f990b052fe16cb1e8\Setup.exe /x86 /x64 /ia64 /web
Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
Operation: Installing
Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup
Package Version = 4.0.30319
User Experience Data Collection Policy: AlwaysUploaded
Number of applicable items: 11
Exe (C:\ea195f990b052fe16cb1e8\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
ServiceControl operation succeeded!
ServiceControl operation succeeded!
Exe (C:\Temp\Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup_4.0.30319\Windows6.1-KB958488-v6001-x64.msu)   failed with 0xc80003f3 - (null).
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0xC80003F3) (Elapsed time: 0 00:09:16).

Do you have idea what I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread that looks similar to what you describe:

http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msestart/thread/27315515-db99-428e-a424-f5d1508f7ba1

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Yup, I have this problem and the link is dead now. Yay.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did and it fixed it - Thanks to Mary.

Create a batch file with the following and run it from a command prompt.

```
regsvr32 MSXML3.dll /s  
net stop wuauserv  
cd /d %windir%\SoftwareDistribution  
rd /s /q DataStore  
net start wuauserv   
regsvr32 softpub.dll   
regsvr32 mssip32.dll
```

- Go to services and stop the Windows Update service
- Go to the Windows directory (default is c:\Windows) and rename the "SoftwareDistribution"   folder to "SoftwareDistribution.old"
- Go to services and start the Windows Update service

From: http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msestart/thread/27315515-db99-428e-a424-f5d1508f7ba1

Answer (score -1):

Thanks dam it worked, k just to make it simpler:

1. Open CMD as Administratior
2. copy
3. regsvr32 MSXML3.dll /s
4. net stop wuauserv
5. cd /d %windir%\SoftwareDistribution
6. rd /s /q DataStore
7. net start wuauserv
8. regsvr32 softpub.dll
9. regsvr32 mssip32.dll

paste there, stuff will happen open net in admin bam

Comment: can you clean this answer up? It hard to understand what you're suggesting?